# Openlayers requests do not complete

Tags: openlayers-3

I have created an OpenLayers application, but when my internet connection is slow some of the requests to the map server do not complete.

The worst part is when you try to change the zoom in / out; the OpenLayers app does not try to download the images again. I guess because are already in the cache.

So how do I create some validation so when map pieces do not download, the program tries again?

Or at least: how I do to remove bad map pieces from the cache?

**Network Traffic From Browser**

[image: an overview of my network traffic in browser]

Answer (score 0):

I see that you're using MapServer.  If your spatial data doesn't change often, you could produce a cache of tiles using [MapCache](http://mapserver.org/el/mapcache/index.html).  That would speed up the requests for tiles and avoid your issue completely.

Comment: Sound good. Can I installl that Mapcache in my pc caching that Mapserver source and point my application to Mapcache, Or is that a module to improve Mapserver performance. Because the Mapserver isnt in my control.

Comment: Yes, you can install MapCache separately and make it connect to a remote WMS server.  See this documentation page, which demonstrate that: http://mapserver.org/el/mapcache/config.html#source